# Error while installing mod_perl2

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl2

Good Day.

I try to install mod_perl (2.0.8) on ubuntu, with Apache 2.4.7

first I run

```
$ perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=$HOME/httpd/bin/apxs MP_APR_CONFIG=$HOME/httpd/bin/apr-1-config
```

and than

make && make test produces an errors

```
Connection.xs: In function ‘XS_Apache2__Connection_remote_addr’:
Connection.xs:117: error: ‘conn_rec’ has no member named ‘remote_addr’
Connection.xs: In function ‘XS_Apache2__Connection_remote_ip’:
Connection.xs:134: error: ‘conn_rec’ has no member named ‘remote_ip’
Connection.xs:138: error: ‘conn_rec’ has no member named ‘remote_ip’
make[3]: *** [Connection.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/perlito/mod_perl-2.0.8/WrapXS/Apache2/Connection'
make[2]: *** [subdirs] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/perlito/mod_perl-2.0.8/WrapXS/Apache2'
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/perlito/mod_perl-2.0.8/WrapXS'
make: *** [subdirs] Error 2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

UPDATE

make source_scan give me that error

```
$ make source_scan
/home/perlito/perl5/bin/perl build/source_scan.pl
panic: multiple types without intervening comma in
    ' int(*ap_vhost_iterate_conn_cb)(void* baton, conn_rec* conn, server_rec* s)'
whited-out as
    ' int(*ap_vhost_iterate_conn_cb)(                                          )'
panic: multiple types without intervening comma in
    ' void(*Perl_ophook_t)(PerlInterpreter* my_perl , OP*)'
whited-out as
    ' void(*Perl_ophook_t)(                              )'
panic: multiple types without intervening comma in
    ' void(*Perl_cpeep_t)(PerlInterpreter* my_perl , OP *, OP *)'
whited-out as
    ' void(*Perl_cpeep_t)(                                     )'
panic: multiple types without intervening comma in
    ' void(*globhook_t)(PerlInterpreter* my_perl )'
whited-out as
    ' void(*globhook_t)(                         )'
Expecting parenth after identifier in `regexp_engine const * Perl_current_re_engine(PerlInterpreter* my_perl )'
after `regexp_engine ' at lib/ModPerl/CScan.pm line 819.
 at lib/ModPerl/CScan.pm line 819.
    ModPerl::CScan::do_declaration('regexp_engine const * Perl_current_re_engine(PerlInterpreter*...', 'HASH(0x92323f0)', 'HASH(0x9241a80)') called at lib/ModPerl/CScan.pm line 762
    ModPerl::CScan::do_declarations('ARRAY(0x921b1a8)', 'HASH(0x92323f0)', 'HASH(0x9241a80)') called at /home/perlito/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/Data/Flow.pm line 93
    Data::Flow::request('Apache2::ParseSource::Scan=ARRAY(0x92329b0)', 'parsed_fdecls') called at /home/perlito/perl5/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/Data/Flow.pm line 46
    Data::Flow::get('Apache2::ParseSource::Scan=ARRAY(0x92329b0)', 'parsed_fdecls') called at lib/Apache2/ParseSource.pm line 68
    Apache2::ParseSource::Scan::get('Apache2::ParseSource::Scan=ARRAY(0x92329b0)', 'parsed_fdecls') called at lib/Apache2/ParseSource.pm line 413
    Apache2::ParseSource::get_functions('Apache2::ParseSource=HASH(0x92327d0)') called at lib/Apache2/ParseSource.pm line 509
    Apache2::ParseSource::write_functions_pm('Apache2::ParseSource=HASH(0x92327d0)') called at build/source_scan.pl line 18
make: *** [source_scan] Error 255
```

Comment: This [perl-dev mailing list message](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-dev/201206.mbox/%3C4FCDAA04.4090209@redhat.com%3E) could be useful in the context of your question.

Comment: IS there a reason why you're not just installing the pre-packaged Ubuntu version? `$ sudo apt-get install apache2`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately upstream mod_perl is not ported to Apache 2.4 yet.

AFAIK Debian developers went ahead and made some changes that allows you to compile and use mod_perl on Apache 2.4. Here is their source tree http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/perl/modperl/branches/httpd24

Comment: this is the correct answer, this is needed to build on OSX yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands before `make`:

```
    make source_scan
    make xs_generate
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve that problem by installing apache2 via apt-get and installing Apache2::RequestRec via cpan